# git svn branch results in "Server SSL certificate verification failed"

Tags: git-svn

Using `git svn` works without issue for all operations except when I try to use `git svn branch`.

When I try `git svn branch newbranch -m "another branch"` from a local repo that was previously successfully cloned using `git svn clone --stdlayout`, I get the following error:

> Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://mysvnserver.blah/path/to/svn/project/trunk': Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 1199.

The error doesn't make a lot of sense as `git svn` works correctly with other commands (eg. `rebase`, `dcommit` etc). And `dcommit` does successfully write changes back to the remote subversion repository.

I am using git version 2.10.2.windows.1

Comment: Running into the same issue with version 2.11.1.windows.1.
I tried changing the repo to HTTP only so no certificate checking is done but it still fails with a different error.

`Can't call method "full_pushurl" on an undefined value at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 1117.`

Answer (score -1):

From the git-svn [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn),

```
branch
Create a branch in the SVN repository.
```

It creates a branch in the svn repository, This will commit to svn repository. This is possible only if you have **write access** to the **repository root** which you would have **cloned using git**. Just provide the write access in svn repository and it should work.

Comment: I *do* have write access, otherwise `dcommit` would not work. I can use svn directly to make changes - eg use TortoiseSvn to create folders etc.

Comment: could you try `git svn fetch` does it report the same error ? and Also does your `repository root` have write access ?

Comment: No. All `git svn` commands that I've tried work correctly, *except* for `branch`

Comment: can you clear subversion cache folder (.subversion) and try again ? It can be found in "C:\Users\<Username>\.subversion". This should prompt to accept certifcate if their is any error.

Comment: Tried that with a `git svn dcommit`. Re-prompted for username/password, committed successfully to repo. No mention of the certificate